# Unexpected behavior using FromDigits to reconstruct polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have an issue with the reconstruction of a polynomial using FromDigits.

The documentation of the function CoefficientList says:

Fold the operation for multivariate polynomials:

`CoefficientList[(x + 2 y)^3, {x, y}]`

> {{0, 0, 0, 8}, {0, 0, 12, 0}, {0, 6, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}

`Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, %, {x, y}]`

> x^3 + 6 x^2 y + y^2 (12 x + 8 y)

Now remove the third power and try this minimal example:

`CoefficientList[x + 2 y, {x, y}]`

> {{0, 2}, {1, 0}}

`Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, %, {x, y}]`

> 1/x + x y

I'm pretty sure I am missing something here, maybe something with small order polynomials as adding anything higher than first order solves the issue.

However in my problem I need to reconstruct a polynomial of order one in one of its variables...

Sorry if this is very simple but I did google it and read through the documentation several times...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I think you are getting bitten by some internal listability. In any case, `In[236]:= FromDigits[{{1, 0}, 0}, x]

Out[236]= 1/x` is probably not what you are anticipating for the behavior. Now make that second `0` into the list `{0,2}` and you get the behavior you are seeing. Again, not what you had wanted. Mapping `FromDigits` seems like a viable way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the result you want like

```
 Total@Flatten[ 
    MapIndexed[  #1 x^(#2 - 1)[[1]] y^(#2 - 1)[[2]] & , 
     CoefficientList[(x + 2 y)^3, {x, y}], {2}] ]
```

I frankly cant follow how the documented procedure is suppoded to work (it seems
 to be using an undocumented form of `FromDigits` )

### multi variable generalization

```
 polyFromCL[cl_List, v0_: True] := Module[{v},
     If[TrueQ@v0, v = Array[x, Length[Dimensions[cl]]], v = v0];
        Total@Flatten[
          MapIndexed[
           Times @@ Append[MapThread[ #1^(#2 - 1) & , {v, #2}], #1] &, 
                 cl, {-1}]]]

 polyFromCL[CoefficientList[(x + 2 y)^3 + x y z, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]
```

> x^3 + 6 x^2 y + 12 x y^2 + 8 y^3 + x y z

Comment: I could expand easily this solution to my situation where I have 3 variables.

`Total@Flatten[
  MapIndexed[#1 x^(#2 - 1)[[1]] y^(#2 - 1)[[2]] z^(#2 - 1)[[3]] &, CoefficientList[(x+2y+3z), {x, y, z}],{3}]]`

Comment: @Klodd Accepting without upvoting will get you 42/6 years of bad luck

Comment: @belisarius I'm hoping to get a reduced sanction with a late upvote :p I'm new to SE as you have noticed ;)

Comment: @Klodd Welcome to the site, again. And hope you keep participating. Very good question, indeed

Answer (score 5):

I was able to trace the "error" in the docs.

The problem is that the example in the docs isn't general enough. The issue is caused by the **two different formats** of the list being interpreted by `FromDigits[]`.
Look, here is the "expected" behavior:

```
FromDigits[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, x]
(* {e + c x + a x^2, f + d x + b x^2} *)
```

but when **only two lists** are present, their meaning is different

```
FromDigits[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, x]
(* {x^(-2 + c) (b + a x), x^(-2 + d) (b + a x)}*)
```

So, as **we need the first form**, we just need to ensure more than two lists.Like this:

```
f[coef_, vars_] := Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, 
                        ArrayPad[coef, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}], 
                        vars] // Expand
```

So:

```
s = CoefficientList[ y ^3 + a  y^2 + c x y + b x, {x, y}];
f[s, {x, y}]
s = CoefficientList[a x + b y , {x, y}];
f[s, {x, y}]

(*
 b x + c x y + a y^2 + y^3
 a x + b y
*)
```

Comment: Good detective work.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau A small modification in the docs could save a headache to more than one user :)

Comment: I reported this as a plausible item for the Possible Issues section.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Nice! So, they are almost, but not quite, entirely unlike going to fix it!

Comment: I never know what will get fixed other than the things that come to me. Even those can be iffy since "fixes" do not always survive testing.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Not uncommon at all. [Re: testers](http://www.brh.org.uk/heads2008/images/web_logo.gif)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the undocumented function `` Internal`FromCoefficientList ``

Examples:

```
cl = CoefficientList[(x + 2 y)^3, {x, y}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 8}, {0, 0, 12, 0}, {0, 6, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}

```
fcl = Internal`FromCoefficientList[cl, {x, y}]
```

> x^3 + 6 x^2 y + 12 x y^2 + 8 y^3

```
FullSimplify[fcl]
```

> (x + 2 y)^3

```
cl2 = CoefficientList[(x + 2 y)^3 + x y z, {x, y, z}]
```

> {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {8, 0}},
>          {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {12, 0}, {0, 0}},
>          {{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
>          {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}}

```
fcl2 = Internal`FromCoefficientList[cl2, {x, y, z}]
```

> x^3 + 6 x^2 y + 12 x y^2 + 8 y^3 + x y z

```
FullSimplify[fcl2]
```

> (x + 2 y)^3 + x y z

Note: This approach works both in Version 9.0.1.0 for Windows (64-bit) and 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (Wolfram Programming Cloud).

Usual caveat regarding using undocumented functions apply.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive algorithm to unfold `CoefficientLists` of arbitrary dimensions:

```
polyFromCL[cl_, {}] := cl
polyFromCL[cl_, vars_] :=
  polyFromCL[
    Fold[(#1 First@vars + #2) &, Reverse@cl],
    Rest@vars
  ]
```

(There must be a way of doing a two dimensional fold.)

```
poly = a x^5 + (x + 2 y)^3 + x y z + 1;
cl = CoefficientList[poly, {x, y, z}];
polyFromCL[cl, {x, y, z}]
Expand[% - poly]

(* 0 *)
```