# How can I do a two dimensional Fold?

Tags: functional-style, code-review

I'd like to `Fold` over higher dimensional objects than lists.  Semantically, the format would be something like `FoldMulti[f, array, list]`.  As a precondition, `Dimensions[array] == Length[list]`.

The motivating example is from the recent discussions about inverse of `CoefficientList`.

Let `poly` be some polynomial, and `cl` be the coefficient list e.g.

```
poly = a x^5 + (x + 2 y)^3 + x y z + 1;
vars = {x, y, z};
cl = CoefficientList[poly, vars];
```

In this example, `array = cl` is 3 dimensional, and `poly` has length 3.  For each variable `var` in `{x,y,z}`, the function `(#1 var + #2) &` should be folded across `cl`, to recreate `poly` from the coefficient array `cl`.

The following code works:

```
Fold[
   Function[{clinner, var}, Fold[(#1 var + #2) &, Reverse@clinner]],
   cl,
   vars
]

% - poly // Expand
(* 0 *)
```

but the problem is that's just a horribly complex bit of code that calls `Fold` twice.

The following works and is pretty enough!  But it uses a different idiom.

```
polyFromCL[cl_, {}] := cl
polyFromCL[cl_, vars_] :=
  polyFromCL[
    Fold[(#1 First@vars + #2) &, Reverse@cl],
    Rest@vars
  ]

polyFromCL[cl, vars]
% - poly // Expand
(* 0 *)
```

Can something like `MapThread` or `Outer` be made to do this elegantly?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the point, but why not `Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, cl, {x, y, z}]` like documentation suggests?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect from this Tensor Fold ?
For this multi-fold do you mean something like: 
`Outer[Fold[f, #1, #2] &, {{o,p}, {q,r}, {s,t}},{{u,v}, {w,x}, {y,z}},1]` 


Maybe `TensorContract[#,{level}]` and the Tensor functions could be helpful.

Comment: @Kuba the example documentation is wrong, see the answers to the question on [Unexpected behaviour using FromDigits](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66484/unexpected-behavior-using-fromdigits-to-reconstruct-polynomial/83090#83090).

Comment: I do not understand why you feel that the first method is a "horribly complex bit of code" -- okay, it's not the embodiment of elegance, but really what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Horribly complex might be exaggerating, but it's the sort of code that is much easier to write than read.  I don't like defining two different functions in a single line of code!  You would avoid using `Table` twice in a single line like that, I'm hoping to avoid using `Fold` twice in much the same way.

Comment: @Histograms I don't know what the general form should be but I will think about it.  I posed the question because I've bumped up against this problem a couple of times and always felt that I was missing a useful idiom.  I hoped that someone would recognise the pattern and say "oh you need to know about `cwyozeg`" :) or similar.

Comment: Could you provide a second example of a two-dimensional Fold operation?  I have trouble separating this *particular* example from the generalized concept.

Comment: I'll try. It was years ago. Got called in to work so it might be a couple of days. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly elegant way for dealing with your example, but I don't see how to generalize it a multi-dimensional `Fold`, what ever that might be.

```
p1 = a x^5 + (x + 2 y)^3 + x y z + 1;
vars = {x, y, z};
cl = CoefficientList[p1, vars];
p2 = Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, cl, vars];
p1 - p2 // Expand
```

> `0`

BTW, I unashamedly stole this from the 2nd example given under **CoefficientList > Examples > Properties & Relations**